# How do i log into Mariadb?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I just installed a MariaDB Database server on my windows 7 32-bit PC. After i'd set up my root password and the installation was complete i tried to log into my MariaDB using the 'mysql -u root -p' command on the command line but it kept on saying: 'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. can someone please help me figure out  what the problem might be? thanks in advance

Comment: Use the full path to `C:\mariaDB\bin\mysql` folder or place that folder on the windows PATH. Or simply `CD` into the bin folder and then run `mysql`

Comment: Clearly the mysql command is not in your current path variable. Either use the console that was created when mariadb was installed, or cd to the directory where the mysql.exe command exists.

Answer (score 0):

When you see this prompt:

```
mysql>
```

You are at the tool for accessing MySQL or MariaDB.  At that point, only type SQL commands such as CREATE, SHOW, SET, SELECT, INSERT, ...  Do not type shell commands such as cd, dir, ls, rm, ....  Nor `mysql`.